# Apache2 URL Rewrite using Joomla - Permission issue? (500 internal error)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I am using LAMP with Joomla 3.3.4 on ubuntu desktop

I am currently using the local ip (192.168.x.x) to access the site as I don't have a domain name yet while I am still developing the web site.
I have been struggling with this problem for months, going over forums that have fixes that seem to work for others but not for me.

I am trying to get rid of the '`index.php`' that shows in URLs which looks really dumb.
Every page that isn't the homepage will look like '`domain.com/index.php/page`' which I want to change to `domain.com/page`.

I have tried all solutions listed in http:// forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=614279
None seem to work for me while they do work for a lot of other people.
This code, top rated, made absolutely no difference to me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The command '`a2enmod rewrite`' outputs that it's already enabled and so say php and joomla.

My `/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` contains no `<Directory>` tags whatsoever, like specified in the '`AllowOverride`' solution. When I added those with the code given it made my whole site go `500 internal error`.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I enable 'use URL rewriting' in Joomla it makes all pages 404 except for the home page (domain.com)

The apache `error.log` is spammed with the following:

- A typo that I fixed which still didn't solve anything
- '`/var/www/html/.htaccess`: Options not allowed here' (which I don't understand)
- 'Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace'

I have no idea what's going on here, any ideas?

**EDIT:**

- The '`public $live_site =`' value in Joomla's configuration.php is currently not set, it is supposed to contain the domain name. When I tried setting '`localhost`' it made my whole site template glitch out without solving the problem. Same for '`192.168.x.x'`
- error.log is spammed with: PHP Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /var/www/html/libraries/joomla/applications/web.php on line X

This is repeated for almost every `.php` file.

- I noticed this Ubuntu error report about apache2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbamv.jpg

*Could this be a permission issue with Ubuntu and Apache2? - I've had permission issues before with software, even joomla, it was unable to modify files until I set the directory permissions. - Normally your host sets permissions correctly, obviously you wouldn't be able to do anything. Though I host it myself.*

**EDIT 2:**

Ubuntu version: `14.04`

Apache2 config files: http://pastebin.com/raw,php?i=6H6rP2aY

Comment: Have a read of the Apache section here: http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs#Apache

Comment: I have tried that about a month ago. It didn't work and I encountered the same problems as above like mine not having a 'Directory section' It also seems to be outdated, the 'Use Apache mod_rewrite option' doesn't exist anymore in Joomla. Neither did it work with the newer 'Rewrite URL option'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem.

I used this guide: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_check_if_mod_rewrite_is_enabled_on_your_server

...to find out if `mod_rewrite` is functioning; It was not. What this means is that the problem does NOT lie in `.htaccess` or your joomla settings, but in apache.

If apache is not configured correctly, `.htaccess` will be ignored.

In my configs the `AllowOverride` was set to target `/var/www/` instead of `/var/www/html/`. Updating that fixed the problem for me.

I hope this may help other people as well, and if you find that your apache setup passes the guide I mentioned, then your problem lies in your website; your `.htaccess` or joomla configs.